# Aggregating (customer) data in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I am currently working with a large customer purchase dataset containing purchases over multiple years.

As I am only interested in checking whether a customer has purchased within each year, I am looking for an efficient way to aggregate these purchases on customer level.

The end result should look somewhat as a table in which each row represents an unique customer, displayed by its I'd followed by some true/false variables showing whether or not he bought during a specific year. a quick example:

Raw data looks similar to:

[Raw data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8w7T.png)

```
Customer id Product id  year
1           1           2014
2           2           2014
1           3           2015
```

Result should look similar to:

[Result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj9Vy.png)

```
Customer id Bought 2014 Bought 2015
1           TRUE        TRUE
2           TRUE        FALSE
```

I have tried creating this by using an for - if loop in order to create the true or false variables however this appears to have a huge run-time, which makes it unusable for the size of the dataset I'm using. 
Also if I were to use the for - if loop, I'm still struggling to get the data aggregated on customer level as I am unsure what to use as the 'FUN =' statement.

Comment: maybe just with `table`; `with(df, table(customerID, year) > 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `dplyr` and `tidyr` approach that should accommodate any number of years in your raw data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(customer_id) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, year) %>% 
  spread(value, variable) %>% 
  summarize_each(funs(as.logical(sum(!is.na(.)))), -customer_id, -product_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kevin try code bellow this uses `dplyr`:

```
#create your data.frame
test <- data.frame(cus=c(1,2,1),prod=c(1,2,3),year=c(2014,2014,2015))

summary <- test %>% 
  group_by(cus) %>% 
  summarise(bought.2014 = any(year==2014),
            bought.2015 = any(year==2015)
 )
```